# HQl query to retrieve data from Pipe row

Tags: hibernate, oracle11g

I had tried to fetch data which is returning as Array in oracle which is written in a function of oracle as pipe row.

When i tried using native query like select ar_0th_element from table(fn_name(arg)).

the above code works fine in native sql query.

how to do the same thing using hql.

Answer (score 0):

HQL, much like JPQL, are languages that are designed to work on *entities*. Your table-valued function `TABLE(fn_name(arg))` is not an entity, so it's best to stick to native SQL.

If your table-valued function actually returns values that can be *mapped* to entities, you can still do this using native SQL, by calling [`EntityManager.createNativeQuery(String, Class)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-)